# How to update each field in a list using Play json in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have the following json string:

```
{
   "id":123,
   "students":[
      {
         "collected":{
            "field":"field_1"
         },
         "attr":[{
            "name":"test_name",
            "age":"17",
            "color":"blue"
         }]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to update all the elements in "attr" object in all of my "students" list.
By updating, I mean that I need to update the values into the concatenated string of the key and value

```
{
   "id":123,
   "students":[
      {
         "collected":{
            "field":"field_1"
         },
         "attr":[{
            "name":"nametest_name",
            "age":"age17",
            "color":"colorblue"
         }]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have come across into transform method of JsValue. This is my transformer:

```
val jsonTransformer = (__ \ 'students).json.update(
  of[JsArray].map{
    case JsArray(list) =>
      list.map(o => o)
  }
)
```

My transformer is not changing anything because I can't seem to find a way to traverse to the "attr" field.

Can anyone provide me an insight?

Comment: is attribute an array of json object or just one single json object?
In your input json, you've created as an array and in the expected output you have just one single attr object for each student?

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed the output. Can you check again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking following as input (where `attr` is an array of objects):

```
   val input =
      """
        |{
        |   "id":123,
        |   "students":[
        |      {
        |         "collected":{
        |            "field":"field_1"
        |         },
        |         "attr":[{
        |            "name":"test_name",
        |            "age":"17",
        |            "color":"blue"
        |         }]
        |      },
        |      {
        |         "collected":{
        |            "field":"field_2"
        |         },
        |         "attr":[{
        |            "name":"test_name2",
        |            "age":"18",
        |            "color":"red"
        |         }]
        |      }
        |   ]
        |}
        |""".stripMargin
```

We can apply following transformer to get the required results:

```
    val attrTransformer = (__ \ "attr").json.update {
      __.read[JsArray].map {
        case JsArray(values) =>

          val updatedValues = values.map { x =>
            JsObject(x.as[JsObject].fields.map { z =>
              val (key, value) = z
              (key, JsString(key + value.as[String]))
            })
          }

          JsArray(updatedValues)
      }
    }

    val transformer = (__ \ "students").json.update(Reads.list(attrTransformer).map(x => JsArray(x)))

    val output = json.transform(transformer).get
```

The output after transformation will be:

```
{
  "students" : [ {
    "collected" : {
      "field" : "field_1"
    },
    "attr" : [ {
      "name" : "nametest_name",
      "age" : "age17",
      "color" : "colorblue"
    } ]
  }, {
    "collected" : {
      "field" : "field_2"
    },
    "attr" : [ {
      "name" : "nametest_name2",
      "age" : "age18",
      "color" : "colorred"
    } ]
  } ],
  "id" : 123
}
```

### Old Answer

Considering the below input (where `attr` is not an array of `JsObject`):

```
    val input =
      """
        |{
        |   "id":123,
        |   "students":[
        |      {
        |         "collected":{
        |            "field":"field_1"
        |         },
        |         "attr":{
        |            "name":"test_name",
        |            "age":"17",
        |            "color":"blue"
        |         }
        |      },
        |      {
        |         "collected":{
        |            "field":"field_2"
        |         },
        |         "attr":{
        |            "name":"test_name2",
        |            "age":"18",
        |            "color":"red"
        |         }
        |      }
        |   ]
        |}
        |""".stripMargin
```

A simple solution would be to create a new JsObject with updated values as below.
(without any validations)

```
    val students = (Json.parse(input) \ "students").as[JsArray]
    val requiredStudents = students.value.map { student =>
      val attr = student \ "attr"

      val updatedAttributes = attr.get.as[JsObject].fields.map { x =>
        val (key, value) = x
        (key, JsString(key + value.as[String]))
      }

      val requiredStudent = student.as[JsObject] ++ Json.obj("attr" -> JsObject(updatedAttributes))
      requiredStudent
    }

    requiredStudents.foreach(println)
```

The output for each student will be as follows:

```
{"collected":{"field":"field_1"},"attr":{"name":"nametest_name","age":"age17","color":"colorblue"}}
{"collected":{"field":"field_2"},"attr":{"name":"nametest_name2","age":"age18","color":"colorred"}}
```

Comment: Wow that's great. I'm just thinking if I can do this with transformer?

Comment: @labyrinthdeux - Can you please check the updated answer and see if it helps

Comment: I just also figured it out. And we have almost similar answer. Thanks for your help. Will accept your answer